# Alternative approach in Azure for multi server Administration SQL agent job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Currently in my organization having total 15 QA and 5 UAT SQL environments. As of now we are managing all SQL agent jobs using multi server administration feature of SQL server in one of target server. Now we are planning to migrate these all SQL environments database on Azure. In azure we are using SQL Database service not any VM box. 
So, Is there any feature or alternative solution to manage all jobs of all environment in one of central location in azure. All SQL jobs are type of T-SQL only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro) to centralize all your Azure SQL Database jobs in one place.

You can use the following [PowerShell Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow) on Azure Automation to schedule execution of any stored procedure on any Azure SQL Database no matter on which Azure SQL logical server they reside.

```
workflow SQL_Agent_SprocJob
{
[cmdletbinding()]
param
(
# Fully-qualified name of the Azure DB server
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string] $SqlServerName,
# Name of database to connect and execute against
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string] $DBName,
# Name of stored procedure to be executed
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string] $StoredProcName,
# Credentials for $SqlServerName stored as an Azure Automation credential asset
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[PSCredential] $Credential
)
inlinescript
{
Write-Output “JOB STARTING”
# Setup variables
$ServerName = $Using:SqlServerName
$UserId = $Using:Credential.UserName
$Password = ($Using:Credential).GetNetworkCredential().Password
$DB = $Using:DBName
$SP = $Using:StoredProcName
# Create & Open connection to Database
$DatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = “Data Source = $ServerName; Initial Catalog = $DB; User ID = $UserId; Password = $Password;”
$DatabaseConnection.Open();
Write-Output “CONNECTION OPENED”
# Create & Define command and query text
$DatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$DatabaseCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$DatabaseCommand.Connection = $DatabaseConnection
$DatabaseCommand.CommandText = $SP
Write-Output “EXECUTING QUERY”
# Execute the query
$DatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
# Close connection to DB
$DatabaseConnection.Close()
Write-Output “CONNECTION CLOSED”
Write-Output “JOB COMPLETED”
}
}
```

Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual) step-by-step tutorial to get started.

Comment: Thank you Morillo for your inputs. Currently I am exploring Elastic Agent Job feature of Azure which give same functionality. Meanwhile I will check your solution also. After that I can finalize suitable and manageable approach for my solution. Thanks Again.

Comment: Management of elastic jobs is primarily PowerShell. That may be an issue. I hope you find the solution you are looking for.